# how to change appearence of the content of default post list columns?

Tags: filters, admin, actions, list, table

Speaking about backoffice here.

I usually add columns and filters to the backoffice for certain custom post types. No problem here. BUt what if I would simply like to change something on the content of the default columns? For example, how to change the color of the post titles?
And say, only some titles on a list, for example based on the terms the post belongs to?

I would just need an action like

```
manage_{$post->post_type}_posts_custom_column
```

But for regular/default columns. The above action only reach custom columns.

Answer (score 2):

CSS is the answer. If you look at the HTML code of each row (`<tr>`), you will see that it has classes that include post ID, post status, post tags, categories, and so on. So, you can easily apply CSS rules based on that classes and based on post tags.

For example, this is a row in one of my site:

```
<tr id="post-24392" class="post-24392 type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-ciencia-y-tecnologia tag-distancia tag-longitud tag-metro tag-sistema-internacional-de-unidades alternate iedit author-other level-0">
            <th scope="row" class="check-column">
                            <label class="screen-reader-text" for="cb-select-24392">Elige ¿?</label>
            <input id="cb-select-24392" type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="24392">
            <div class="locked-indicator"></div>
                        </th>
        <td class="post-title page-title column-title">
        Here the title
```

If I want to change the color of the title if the post belongs to "metro" tag:

```
.tag-metro .post-title {
    color: red;
}
```

You can put that CSS in a file and [enqueue it in admin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts).

If terms are from a custom taxonomy, you can hook post_class to add the classes based on the custom taxonomy:

```
add_filter( 'post_class', function( $classes, $class, $ID ) {

    $taxonomy = 'my-custom-taxonomy';

    $terms = get_the_terms( (int) $ID, $taxonomy );

    if( !empty( $terms ) ) {

        foreach( (array) $terms as $order => $term ) {

            if( !in_array( $term->slug, $classes ) ) {

                $classes[] = $term->slug;

            }

        }

    }

    return $classes;

}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: This is a good answer but sadly not THE answer for me: classes on TR don't include terms. I need to color based on terms of a custom taxonomy. So I'd really need some kind of hook. Really strange that there isn't one for defaults but there's one for customs, by the way.

Comment: Why `<tr>` classes doesn't include terms for you? Are the terms from a custom taxonomy? See edited answer.

Comment: yes, custom taxonomy, just as commented before

Answer (score 0):

Unluckily does not exists a filter like that. However, output pass throught WordPress *usual* filters. E.g. `'the_title'` for title.

The only problem is that you can't just add a filter to the `'the_title'`, because it will affect a lot of things. However you can use filters that are triggered only on post list admin screen (`edit.php`) to add the filter to title.

As example:

```
// this filter is fired only on edit.php for 'post' post type
add_filter('manage_edit-post_sortable_columns', function($sortable) {

    // add a filter to post title. Use the lowest possible priority. 
    add_filter('the_title', 'my_admin_title_color', PHP_INT_MAX);

    return $sortable;
});

function my_admin_title_color($title) {
    // you can use template tags or even access to global $post
    if ( has_category('uncategorized') ) {
        $title = '<span style="color:#f00">'.$title.'</span>';
    }

    return $title;
}
```

In code above I used `'manage_edit-post_sortable_columns'` because is a filter that is fired only on `edit.php` for 'post' post type.

It is one of the [`"manage_{$screen_id}_sortable_columns"`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_this-screen-id_sortable_columns/), filters that is triggered with a different name for different post types. As example you ca use `"manage_edit-page_sortable_columns"` to target pages. This *specificity* allow to add pretty safely the widely used `the_title` filter hook. Moreover by using a very low priority compatibility with other filters should be assured.

After that you can just wrap the title with a span with some custom styles (as done in my example code), or some custom HTML class to be styles with external CSS.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't escape properly and the tags are actually printed out in the title as-is and not as code that is used in markup.